# Can I call ".log" on a variable

Tags: javascript, asp.net, function, math

I'm new to javascript and searched all over for an answer for this but to no avail and I'm short on time.  I'm updating some code and they have the following code in a function.

```
var mbytes = 512;
mbytes = parseFloat(mbytes);
var nbbytes = mbytes.log(1024);
```

I understand that it should be using the Math.log() function.  It works in the old code, but when I'm writing my own function using the variable mbytes.log I get an "Uncaught TypeError: Undefined is not a function".  I know this is because mbytes is not function but a variable.  It doesn't make sense to me why it works fine in the old code but errors if I try to do that now? Is it possible to call the .log function on a variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have a flot value, it is of type `Number` and `Number` does not have a method called `log` in it.

But you can easily add a method to the [prototype object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) of number and implement the logic there

```
Number.prototype.log = function (param) {
    var value = this;
    //do your logic here
    console.log(value, param)
    return Math.log(value)
}

var mbytes = 512;
mbytes = parseFloat(mbytes);
var nbbytes = mbytes.log(1024);
console.log(nbbytes)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mdabm954/)

- [Object.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype)
- [Inheritance and the prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)